# WebDriver Drag and Drop in application using Dragula

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, dragula

My company has a new application that incorporates drag and drop. The drag and drop is done via the Dragula library.

I'm trying to automate this functionality, but I'm not having any luck. I have tried both WebDriver's built in DragAndDrop() method (which my understanding is it doesn't normally work so well with modern web tech). I tried constructing my own Drag and Drop with Actions. And I've also tried using jquery in the javascript executor. Neither of these methods have worked.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I found a work around here: https://github.com/bevacqua/angular-dragula/issues/86 However this doesn't work, since we cannot expose our Dragula method.

Comment: What do you mean you cannot expost your Dragula Method? Kindly provide a [MCVE]

Comment: @JeremyThompson The Dragula object is created in a function. For that workaround to work, it would need to have a global scope. According to our developers, this is not doable.

Comment: @Andrio did you find a work around for this? as I face similar issue please update with answer if you found any?

Comment: @swathi I'm sorry, I never did find a work around. We ended up deciding for the developers to implement a work around to dragging and dropping.

Comment: @Andrio there is a workaround :) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46434071/5831897)

Answer (score 1):

If `DragAndDrop()` method didn't work for you can build your own using other methods from [Actions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html)

```
IWebElement source;
IWebElement target;

Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.ClickAndHold(source).Perform();
actions.MoveByOffset(target.Location.X - source.Location.X, target.Location.Y - source.Location.Y).Perform();
actions.Release(target).Perform();
```

This will scroll vertically and horizontally.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the Actions class failed as well.